# Convert A Text File From Resources Into Array

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to read a txt file I uploaded in Resources folder and then I have to convert it into an a string[] array. Anyway, when I debug the code, at the second line I get the following exception: System.ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path'.

I've tried this method with a file from my computer and it works. I checked my text for special characters but I havent'found anything. I removed space at the beginning of a line.

```
          string text = Convert.ToString(Resources.File);
          string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(text).ToArray();
```

Try with file from computer: it works.

```
        string text = Convert.ToString(@"C: \File.txt");
        if (File.Exists(text))
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(text);
            int i = 1;

            if (lines[i] == abc.Text)
            {
                DO STUFF;
                f2.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
```

I except the file to be converted.

Comment: The `Resources.File` is a string. Just split it by `Enivironment.NewLine`.

Answer (score 2):

When you add a `.txt` file to a `.resx` resource, the designer will create a string property for that.

Assuming the property name is `MyFile`, then to get the lines you just need to split the string using `Environment.NewLine`:

```
var lines = Properties.Resources.MyFile
    .Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

**Note:** If for any reason, you are interested to have the `byte[]` for a `.txt` file, you can set the file type in resource designer to binary:

[image]