# Writing a string into a text file from resources

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to write a string called "a" into a text file from resources which is called "file.txt". Anyway, I always get "Invalid Characters in path" error. String "a" is obtained by string.join of "\r\n" with an array called "lines" with has no empty entries.

I've tried using a regex to replace invalid characters but it has not worked.

I'd like to string a to be saved into the text.

```
        string a = string.Join("\r\n", lines);
        string ee = Regex.Replace(a, @"[\[\]\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\{\}%,;><!@#&\-\+/]", "");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Properties.Resources.file, ee);
```

Comment: It's already mentioned in [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55881114/3110834), `Properties.Resources.SomeFIle` will return the content of the embedded resource. It's not a file on file-system and you cannot change it. It's embedded.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with `Properties.Resources.file`  it has illegal characters.   `a` is fine, you do not have to do any regex on it to solve this problem.

If you don't know what Properties.Resources.file is, try breakpointing on that line and checking what `Properties.Resources.file` is set to

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify your `Properties.Resources` files like this.
The error you are getting is because the path (`Properties.Resources.xxxx`) you are referring to is not a valid path.

Try and save the string to an actual file e.g:

```
    string a = string.Join("\r\n", lines);
    string ee = Regex.Replace(a, @"[\[\]\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)\{\}%,;><!@#&\-\+/]", "");
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("output.txt", ee);
```

This would create a file called 'output.txt' in the current directory your application is running. Make sure the application does have write permissions in this directory.

Alternatively, you could make use of `Properties.Settings`, where you can define a variable and perform read/write operations to it during runtime.